# How to copy an XML file and save it to the local device using python?

Tags: python, xml

I want to copy a XML with its tags and modify it, and then save this copy to the local desktop.

So I use python language to open the XML file using ElementTree library.

And here is the code of python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Copy the test.xml file and save it to the local
    
mytree.write('test.xml')
```

Is there any Idea how can I copy the existing XML file and modify it and then save it to the local?

Comment: describe the problem with your current code plz. maybe you call write on the modified tree.

Comment: @marco-f I didn't code it, I just want to know how can I copy an xml file and modify it then save it to the local

Comment: Load/parse the source xml. Modify it and save with different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, it works for your solution,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('./xml_stackoverflow.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for compattrval in root.iter('CompAttrVal'):
    compattrval_value = int(compattrval) + 1
    # update the text of compattrval
    compattrval.text = str(compattrval_value)
    # update name attribute value or if it's not exist it will create a new attribute name
    compattrval.set('name', 'updated_value') 
tree.write('output.xml')
```